# Control existing Internet Explorer with c++

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com

Use case: Someone asked me to automate his internet explorer. Every day, he has to navigate to the same URL, enter the same credentials und log in. He'd like the computer to do that automatically: With an application that navigates to the URL, enters the post data and logs in automatically. He then can continue to navigate manually through the page.

So, if I want to control directly an existing internet explorer instance, how would I do that with C++?

Comment: I do not have a tested answer but this answer to my question could give a hint of a direction where to look and research: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8285218/341065

Comment: (almost) everything is "possible" with modern computers, the point is: why would one want to do such a thing ? If you want to build a separate application, then why not include the code that downloads the page you are looking for? But such apps already exists... (search for `wget`). Could you clarify the use case?

Comment: From a usability standpoint, you should not commandeer an existing Internet Explorer instance. (What if the user had an unsaved email message in it?) You should create your own instance and use that. `IWebBrowser2` gives you methods for manipulating an IE window.

Comment: I've just updated my post in order to clarify the use case.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of research, I managed to open a new instance of the IE and navigating to a specific URL.

The steps I undertook:

1. Link the following libraries in the project options: libole32.a, liboleaut32.a, liboleacc.a, libuuid.a
2. Include cassert and exdisp.h at the beginning of the main cpp-file.
3. Insert the following code in the main cpp-file:

```
int main(void) {
```

`HRESULT hret;
hret=CoInitialize(NULL); 
assert(SUCCEEDED(hret));

CLSID clsid;            // Get IE CLSID
hret=CLSIDFromProgID(L"InternetExplorer.Application",&clsid);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hret));

IUnknown *p;            // Get IUnknown Interface
hret=CoCreateInstance(clsid,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,IID_IUnknown,reinterpret_cast<void**>(&p));
assert(SUCCEEDED(hret));

IDispatch *q;           // Get IDispatch Interface from IUnknown
hret=p->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch,reinterpret_cast<void**>(&q));
assert(SUCCEEDED(hret));

IWebBrowser2 *r;        // Get IWebBrowser2 Interface from IDispatch
hret=q->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2,reinterpret_cast<void**>(&r));
assert(SUCCEEDED(hret));

IUnknown *s;            // Get IUnknown from IWebBrowser2
hret=r->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown,reinterpret_cast<void**>(&s));
assert(SUCCEEDED(hret));

///// Transitive //////////////////////////
assert(p==s);
////////////////////////////////////////

VARIANT vEmpty;
VariantInit(&vEmpty);
VARIANT vFlags;
V_VT(&vFlags) = VT_I4;
V_I4(&vFlags) = navOpenInNewWindow;


BSTR bstrURL = SysAllocString(L"http://www.google.com");

r->Navigate(bstrURL, &vFlags, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);
r->Quit();

SysFreeString(bstrURL);

p->Release();  q->Release();  r->Release(); s->Release();  

CoUninitialize(); return 0;

}`